# Using LZMA SDK in C++

Tags: c++, sdk, compression, 7zip, lzma

I am trying to use LZMA SDK to compress a file in my program. I have download the SDK but I don't know how to use it. Can anyone tell me what steps I need to take to make this work? Any help would be highly appreciated

I am almost a newbie to C and C++ world

Comment: Hi Milad, platform and development environment? Providing that sort of information makes our life easier. There is a general answer, but there might be a specific way of doing it based on your platform.

Answer (score 6):

I also had a need to use 7zip in one of my programs, and found the LZMA SDK a little more daunting than I first expected.  So I've started a simplified C++ wrapper for it, [here](https://bitbucket.org/cmcnab/sevenzip/overview).  It's currently Windows-only, but if that's your platform you might find it useful.

Comment: Although your SevenZip++ library isn't documented very thoroughly, it is written so clearly that it is still extremely useful as a tutorial on how to use the LZMA + 7zip SDK. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

As a general answer to this question to get *any* sdk to work, you need to do three things:

- `#include` the appropriate headers in your source so that the compiler can check you've used the right functions and the linker knows which symbols you're refering to.
- Tell the compiler where your header files are. You can do this with gcc using `gcc -I/path/to/header/dir`.
- Tell the linker where the libs are that are to be compiled in and to include them. Again, using gcc, you do this with `gcc -L/path/to/library/dir` and you tell gcc (well, ld) to link to a specific library using `gcc -lnamewithoutlibprefix` (lowercase l).

As an example for a library I use a lot, MPIR, against the /opt tree, I might compile like this:

```
gcc -I/opt/include -L/opt/lib -lmpir myprog.c -o myprog
```

That's just an example and is very Linux-specific. In truth, MPIR is installed in /usr and I don't need to do this, I'm just picking on it by way of example here.

For Windows, take a look at [cl /I](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73f9s62w%28VS.80%29.aspx), and [LINK.EXE options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx).

Of course, you can automate this process under a number of different development environments. Visual Studio, for example, will generate the correct command lines for you if you fill in the right dialog boxes. So I believe will Eclipse and I know Dev/C++ can, too.

Comment: well, is it possible to somehow embed an executable file in my own program?? Cuz there's a command line version of LZMA SDK called 7za.exe and I can use it to compress and decompress files using system() command in my program but I am wondering if I can put it in my own program ..